# How to ensure only even numbers are entered in edittext in textwatcher?

Tags: android

I need to enter only even numbers(range:0-20) in edittext in textwatcher. However, when i did the following, it remained same that is it is allowing both even and odd numbers to be entered. I want when a user enters an odd number the toast is displayed. guide me please!

> even

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {

                int v = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                if(v%2!=0){
                if (v > 20) {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), "", 0, 2);
                } else if (v < 0) {
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), "", 0, 1);
                }
              }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex)

            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `v&2!=0` are you attempting to use a modulo? `v % 2 == 0` might give you a result you are expected.

Comment: sorry i edited the question. still it is not working. :/ Any other solution.

Comment: You have ```v > 20``` ?

Comment: @KrisKrause: my aim is to enter any even number ranging from 0-20. the first part is good: that is it is giving me toast when i try to put greater than 20. however, it is not giving me the same toast when i am putting odd numbers. help

Answer (score 2):

You are just showing the Toast when a NumberFormatException exception is thrown, meaning that the string does not contain a number.
 So you have to show the toast also when the number is even, and you will do it on the else condition of

```
if(v%2 != 0){
   //Number is odd
}else{
   //Number is even
}
```

Try like the following:

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
         try {
             int v = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
             if(v>0 && v<20){
                   if(v%2 != 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ODD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "EVEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
              }else{
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "OUT OF RANGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
          }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "INVALID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
```

Comment: can you jest edit your answer with the range being included please.thanks

Comment: Sure. Then add your code in each case of the if-else statements to do whatever you want to do with the input text

Comment: i tried it and it partly works..i mean when i am going to enter number 14, it is giving me toast already at 1. i want it to display a toast only when user entered the both digits.can you fix that problem for me please?

Comment: AfterTextChanged is always called when there is a change in your editText. So writing a 2 dígits number will invoke it twice, once for each digit. I guess you have to look for using a different approach. Maybe trying to validate it when it looses focus, or to draw an error message instead of showing a Toast like when using inputTextLayouts

Comment: Maybe there could be errors because of the s.replace part? Can u guide me on that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the replaces?